# JSON_ENCODE for multidimensional array giving different results

Tags: php, arrays, json

When using json_encode for a multidimensional array in PHP, I'm noticing an output when naming one of the arrays, but different output when I am not naming them.  For Example:

```
$arrytest = array(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),array('c'=>3),array('d'=>4));
json_encode($arrytest)
```

gives a single array of multiple json objects

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"c":3},{"d":4}];
```

---

whereas simply assigning a name to the middle array

```
$arrytest = array(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),"secondarray"=>array('c'=>3),array('d'=>4));
json_encode($arrytest)
```

creates a single json object with multiple json objects inside

```
{"0":{"a":1,"b":2},"secondarray":{"c":3},"1":{"d":4}};
```

why would the 1st option not return the same reasults like the 2nd except with "1" in place of "secondarray"

Comment: Felix Kling, why did you remove my json-encode tag? I'm not saying you shouldn't have, but rather I want to make sure I'm folllowing the correct procedure for tagging, being that json-encode is in my code, I though it would apply as a proper tag.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In JSON, arrays `[]` only every have numeric keys, whereas objects `{}` have string properties.  The inclusion of a array key in your second example forces the entire outer structure to be an object by necessity.  The inner objects of both examples are made as objects because of the inclusion of string keys `a,b,c,d`.

If you were to use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option on the first example, you should get back a similar structure to the second, with the outer structure an object rather than an array.  Without specifying that you want it as an object, the absence of string keys in the outer array causes PHP to assume it is to be encoded as the equivalent array structure in JSON.

```
$arrytest = array(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),array('c'=>3),array('d'=>4));

// Force the outer structure into an object rather than array
echo json_encode($arrytest , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

// {"0":{"a":1,"b":2},"1":{"c":3},"2":{"d":4}}
```

Comment: Then why call it JAVASCRIPT OBJECT NOTATION, if it had nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks for that explanation I think that will get me headed in the right direction.

Comment: @Brendan Why does it have nothing to do with Javascript?

Comment: @deceze An earlier comment providing context for this was removed.

Comment: Yeah, now it looks stupid that I had that there. For reference, someone said JSON had nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: Heads up, If there is another wrapping array, because why not, you get {{"0": {"a:1"}}}

Answer (score 2):

Arrays with continuous numerical keys are encoded as JSON arrays. That's just how it is. Why? Because it makes sense.

Since the keys can be expressed implicitly through the array encoding, there is no reason to explicitly encoded them as object keys.

See all the examples in the [`json_encode` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: I'm not saying they shouldn't be, that's why I was asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

At the first option you only have numeric indexes (0, 1 and 2). Although they are not explicitly declared, php automatically creates them.

At the second option, you declare one of the indexes as an string and this makes PHP internally transform all indexes to string.

When you json encode the first array, it's not necessary to show the integers in the generated json string because any decoder should be able to "guess" that they are 0, 1 and 2.

But in the second array, this is necessary, as the decoder must know the key value in your array.

It's pretty simple. No indexes declared in array? Them they are 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

output of this as in json form is year1{a,b},year2{c}, year3{d}
**a has value 1 ,b=2,c=3,d=4 stored in array of year1's a,b years2's c and years3's d respectivily

```
$array1 = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2);
    $array2 = array('c'=>3);
    $array3 = array('d'=>4)
    $form = array("year1" =>$array1,
                  "year2" =>$array2,
                  "year3" =>$array3,
            );

    $data = json_encode($form);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it - how does your code explain that the two input arrays result in different outputs?