# How to convert a PHP array to a JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, type-conversion

I am trying to convert my PHP array that i get as a query result to a JSON array. But look like it does not work. Any help would be appriciated.

```
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE companyID = ?");

        if($stmt == "false"){
            die('Query error !'.$db->error);  
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $companyID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt -> get_result();
        $companies = $result ->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);

        echo json_encode(array('companies' => $companies));
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is the result of your current code? What do you expect it to look like?

Comment: I expect a JSON array but there is no JSON array

Comment: `But look like it does not work.` please be even less specific if possible

Comment: Does `$result ->fetch_all` actually give you an *array* or just something array-like?

Comment: What is the result of `echo json_encode(array('companies' => $companies));`?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like what you're experiencing is JSON itself. There is an [existing, excellent answer  here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10778760/1671573) that will explain that. The summary is that an array with string keys in PHP is an object in JSON, since arrays can only have numeric indexes.

I hope this answers your question directly enough, and I think it will change how you think of the relationship between PHP and JSON.