# JSON formatting, Pushing a named Array into an existing Array for each set?

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to fix a problem in my JSON API when I request a multiple result set from my database.  Basically I want to store a named array, "card" for each row returned.  My goal is to get the JSON to look like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "card": {
                "property": "value",
                "property": "value",
                "property": "value"
            }
        },
        {
            "card": {
                "property": "value",
                "property": "value",
                "property": "value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But instead it looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "card": [
                {
                    "property": "value",
                    "property": "value",
                    "property": "value"
                },
                {
                    "property": "value",
                    "property": "value",
                    "property": "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below you can find my code:

```
// Prepare Stored Procedure Call
$dbConn = new ConnDB();
$dbConn->query("CALL " . $this->proc);

//Get Result$$$
$row = $dbConn->resultset();

foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $this->valueArray[$key] = $value;
}

$this->data = array(
    "results" => array(
        array(
            $this->type => $this->valueArray
        ),
    )
);
```

I need to basically build a named array, "card"=>$values, for each $row, but I can't do it in the middle of an array declaration, so the best thing I could think of was this:

```
// Prepare Stored Procedure Call
$dbConn = new ConnDB();
$dbConn->query("CALL " . $this->proc);

//Get Result$$$
$row = $dbConn->resultset();

$jsonArray = array();
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    array_push($jsonArray, $this->type => $this->valueArray[$key] = $value)
}

$this->data = array(
    "results" => array(
        array(
            $jsonArray
        ),
    )
);
```

But that of course gives me parse errors.  Argh!  A bit frustrating.

Any ideas?

Comment: `{}` - it means object, `{card:..,card:...}` - it means object has two different properties with the same name. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So how's this work then?  http://api.randomuser.me/?results=2 its the same thing but "user" instead of "card".

Comment: @wUmpage He is right. There is an array in your `randomuser` API. However, you want to do this with objects notation. Open [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and try to paste your JSON and `randomuser`'s JSON there.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I don't understand it says they're both valid?

Comment: @wUmpage Oh, yes, strange behavior. Look at the content after clicking "validate". It removes duplicated keys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778741/json-encode-of-multidimensional-array-giving-different-results

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I apologize, I made a mistake in my original "ideal" JSON format, please look at it again.  I've made an edit.

Comment: @wUmpage I wonder how you get this output. What does `resultset` return? I just can't understand how you extract several objects from `$row` :(

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev `resultset` is a `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` call in my dbConn class.  Basically it just packages the rows and columns of a database call in an array.  This link shows exactly how it works: http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev your question about how `$row` worked helped me find a solution, thank you.  I realized that it's structure is basically what I needed, I just had to provide a key for it.  I answered my own question, view it if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

YES!  I figured it out.

```
// Prepare Stored Procedure Call
$dbConn = new ConnDB();
$dbConn->query("CALL " . $this->proc);

//Get Result$$$
$row = $dbConn->resultset();

$jsonArray = array();

foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    array_push($jsonArray, array("card" => $value));
}

$this->data = array(
    "results" => $jsonArray,
);
```

This returns the exact format I need. I was overthinking it.

Comment: Nice to hear it. You can mark this answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as follows

```
<?php 
$data = array();
$json_array = array();
$test_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
foreach($test_array as $t){
    $json_array[]['card'] = array('property' => $t);
}
$data['results'] = $json_array;

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**Result**

```
{"results":[{"card":{"property":1}},{"card":{"property":2}},{"card":{"property":3}},{"card":{"property":4}},{"card":{"property":5}},{"card":{"property":6}},{"card":{"property":7}},{"card":{"property":8}},{"card":{"property":9}},{"card":{"property":10}}]}
```

Comment: This was close, unfortunately not much different from how it is formatted now. Please see the first block of code in my question to view correct formatting.

Comment: I will upvote you, as this is similar to what I need, but I found the solution myself and answered my own question.  Thank you so much though!