# How to convert no of days array into json format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have created an array of no of days using the **for loop**

```
$noOfDays=array();
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
    if ($i == '1') {
        $noOfDays[$i]['Number']=$i;
        $noOfDays[$i]['Days']=$i.' Day';
    }else{
         $noOfDays[$i]['Number']=$i;
         $noOfDays[$i]['Days']=$i.' Days';
    }
}
```

and than converted this array into json

```
echo $noOfDaysjson= json_encode($noOfDays);
```

the $noOfDaysjson returns json as below :-

```
{**"1"**:{"Number":1,"Days":"1 Day"},**"2"**:{"Number":2,"Days":"2 Days"},**"3"**:{"Number":3,"Days":"3 Days"},**"4"**:{"Number":4,"Days":"4 Days"},"5":{"Number":5,"Days":"5 Days"},"6":{"Number":6,"Days":"6 Days"},"7":{"Number":7,"Days":"7 Days"},"8":{"Number":8,"Days":"8 Days"},"9":{"Number":9,"Days":"9 Days"},"10":{"Number":10,"Days":"10 Days"},"11":{"Number":11,"Days":"11 Days"},"12":{"Number":12,"Days":"12 Days"},"13":{"Number":13,"Days":"13 Days"},"14":{"Number":14,"Days":"14 Days"},"15":{"Number":15,"Days":"15 Days"},"16":{"Number":16,"Days":"16 Days"},"17":{"Number":17,"Days":"17 Days"},"18":{"Number":18,"Days":"18 Days"},"19":{"Number":19,"Days":"19 Days"},"20":{"Number":20,"Days":"20 Days"},"21":{"Number":21,"Days":"21 Days"},"22":{"Number":22,"Days":"22 Days"},"23":{"Number":23,"Days":"23 Days"},"24":{"Number":24,"Days":"24 Days"},"25":{"Number":25,"Days":"25 Days"},"26":{"Number":26,"Days":"26 Days"},"27":{"Number":27,"Days":"27 Days"},"28":{"Number":28,"Days":"28 Days"},"29":{"Number":29,"Days":"29 Days"},"30":{"Number":30,"Days":"30 Days"},"31":{"Number":31,"Days":"31 Days"}}
```

but i donot want the no. shown like 1, 2 in bold in json format

how can i get json like:-

```
'[{"Number":"1","Days":"1 Day"},{"Number":"2","Days":"2 Days"},{"Number":"3","Days":"3 Days"},{"Number":"4","Days":"4 Days"},....so on]';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
$noOfDays=array();
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
    if ($i == '1') {
        $noOfDays[] = [
            'Number' => $i,
            'Days' => $i. ' Days' 
        ];

    }else{
        $noOfDays[] = [
            'Number' => $i,
            'Days' => $i. ' Day' 
        ];
    }
}

echo $noOfDaysjson= json_encode($noOfDays);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your required json indicates that you want an array of objects, if that is what you actually wanted then this will get that desired result.

```
<?php
$noOfDays=array();
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->Number = $i;
    if ($i == '1') {
        $obj->Days = $i. ' Day';
    }else{
        $obj->Days = $i. ' Days';
    }
    $noOfDays[] = $obj;

}
$noOfDaysjson = json_encode($noOfDays);
echo $noOfDaysjson;
```

Comment: all the answers here returns the same result, but I like your answer the most. up vote.

Comment: @Mohammad Thankyou. Actually all the others missed that request for an array of objects and produced an array of arrays.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, there was no clarification: an array of objects or an array of arrays is implied

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Surely `{}` denotes an object in JSON syntax

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the same way as arrays. Try to `echo $noOfDaysjson = json_encode($noOfDays)` from "array" answers

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest See [the json manual page](http://www.json.org/) I was just applying the rules.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, yes. I got it. It's about associative arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778741/json-encode-of-multidimensional-array-giving-different-results. The only thing that the author doesn't really have to use `stdClass()` in such case, cause `json_encode` will transform an associative array into object anyway

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest True. I just like to make it obvious what I am doing in my code so there is no confusion when I come back to it, or someone else picks it up.

Answer (score 1):

**The shortest and optimized way:**

```
$noOfDays = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++){
    $noOfDays[] = [
        'Number'=> $i,
        'Days' => $i . (($i == 1)? ' Day': ' Days' )
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just make your array multi-dimensional, try this:

```
<?php
$noOfDays=array();
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
    $noOfDays[] = [
                   'Number'=>$i,
                   'Days'=>$i. ($i == '1') ? ' Day' : ' Days'
                  ];
}

echo $noOfDaysjson= json_encode($noOfDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers here are correct...

```
// in case you would like to change your array keys
define ('ARRAY_NUMBER', 'Number');
define ('ARRAY_DAYS',   'Days'  );

// i think it's more clean to avoid if else 31 times
$noOfDays = array();
$noOfDays[] = array(ARRAY_NUMBER    => 1,
                    ARRAY_DAYS      => '1 Day');

for ($i=2 ; $i<=31 ; $i++) {
    $noOfDays[] = array(ARRAY_NUMBER    => $i,
                        ARRAY_DAYS      => $i . ' Days');
}

var_dump(json_encode($noOfDays));
```